# I have no religion, I'm beating a civ about to get a religious victory in combat - how am I able to hamper their religion?

Tags: civilization-6

I have no religion, in combat I'm beating a civ about to get a religious victory.

I now have a bunch of cities with his religion - and the inertia may take him over the religious victory line.

I may not be able to completely wipe him out before he gets his religious victory. Can I remove his religion from my newly captured - or other - cities before he gets his religious win without having a religion of my own?

Comment: I think you may be able to delay his victory if you can make some new cities where his religion won't immediately spread too.

Comment: Interesting, if heavy-handed & expensive, idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you can do to slow down the religious advance is to start targeting the AI religious units. While at war, military units can attack and destroy enemy religious units without taking damage. This is a good way to prevent the AI from spreading their religion to even more cities.

If you have any city that is following a different religion, start buying Missionaries and Apostles to spread that religion in an attempt to counter the spread of the majority religion.
The better option is to buy Inquisitors, if you can. Use them to remove the majority from the cities that are following it. That will be one less city following the near-victory religion.

Comment: yep already targeting religious units. So anyone can buy inquisitors - even if they don't have a religion?

Comment: @niico No, you can only spawn Inquisitors in cities with the adequate religious facilities and a religion, provided that religion has already triggered an Inquisition. The Inquisitors will only clear any foreign religion.

Comment: For clarity: I am suggesting you faith-buy Inquisitors with religious affiliation different than the dominating religion that is about to win a victory. Eric's is correct. Religious units are available for purchase in any city with a Temple, as long as there is a religion influencing that city. Missionaries and Apostles can always be purchased. Inquisitors may be purchased after the founder of the religion has started an inquisition.